# How do I avoid paying tax on a cryptocurrency gain that I have already lost?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, capital-gains-tax, cryptocurrency

I'm not sure if this question belongs here, but I'm super confused about how cryptocurrencies get taxed.

I invested $10,000 at the end of 2020. I made about 30 or so short-term trades in 2021 and sold everything in May. I made $40,000. I re-bought a single cryptocurrency with $50,000 (initial investment + gains) blindly and my total value is now $12,000 since the whole crypto market has been bearish.

Assuming I don't sell it until the end of 2021 and the price does not go up, do I pay tax on $50,000 since it was a profit? If so, what would be my best option to minimize tax on it? I can't cover 25% tax on $50,000 even if I sell everything.

Can I avoid tax on $50,000 if I sell my current position for $12,000?

I live in the U.S.

Comment: @SSpring That's really interesting. I've never heard of it, but it sounds like IRS treats cryptocurrency as property. I'll research it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Why didn’t you keep back 25% to make sure you’d be able to pay the tax on your gains?

Comment: @Tim // I wish I had that wisdom :) Lesson learned.

Comment: You could sell and buy back in immediately. This will realize your losses, which will offset your realized gains without taking yourself out of the position.

Comment: "I invested $10,000 at the end of 2020"   it's very confusing to talk about "investing" when you are trading.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In the U.S., gains from cryptocurrency trading are taxed just like trading stocks: as capital gains.

Capital gains are only taxed when they are [realized](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/71121/10997). At this time, you have realized a $40,000 gain, but you have not realized a loss. If you do not sell your new position before the end of the year, you will be taxed on the $40,000 gain. (Note: your gain is $40,000, not $50,000, because you had a cost basis of $10,000 on your investment, so your gain is $50k - $10k.) Because you only held the asset for less than a year, this is a short-term gain, which means it is taxed at your regular income tax rate. (If you had waited at least a year before you sold, any gain would be a long-term gain and taxed at a lower rate.)

If you were to sell your position today for $12,000, the second trade would have a capital loss of $38,000 ($50k - $12k). When you do your 2021 taxes, assuming you have no other investment gains/losses, you would be taxed on a net gain of $2,000 ($40k - $38k).

A note about the wash sale rule:

If we were talking about securities, you cannot sell your position now and then immediately buy back in and still take that capital loss on your taxes, due to the [wash sale rule](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/102174/10997). If you sell at a loss and wish to claim that loss on your taxes, you must wait a minimum of 30 days before you buy back in.

*However*, [according to CPA Jeffery Levine](https://www.thestreet.com/retirement-daily/ask-the-hammer/does-the-wash-sale-rule-apply-to-crypto-investments), the wash sale rule does not apply to cryptocurrency transactions. That means if you want to continue to hold your position, you could sell now at a loss, buy back in shortly thereafter, and still take that loss on your 2021 taxes.

Comment: Thank you. What confuses me is that I was told that I can only report up to $3,000 per year as a loss. 

Is it correct that I can buy other cryptocurrencies as long as it's not the same one I just sold?

Comment: The $3000 loss limit is only a limit on deducting net losses. You can use your entire loss to offset a gain in the same year. So if you sell today for $12k, your entire $38k loss can be used to offset your $40k gain, resulting in a net gain of $2k that you will be taxed on.

Comment: However, let’s say that you wait until December to sell, and in that time the value of the crypto has gone down to $2k. Your second trade would result in a loss of $48k. This would give you a net capital loss of $8k for the year. You would only be able to deduct $3k of that loss on your 2021 taxes; the other $5k would be carried over to future years to either offset new capital gains or to be deducted on your taxes.

Comment: Miller // Thank you so much! That makes sense now.

Comment: @왕뚜껑 Basically, you can't carry more than $3k off of Schedule D. You can claim as much loss as you had as long as you're offsetting income on Schedule D and for the same year.

Comment: My understanding is that the wash sale rule does not apply to cryptos since they aren't securities.

Comment: @GrandmasterB Thanks for the heads-up. I have edited my answer.

Comment: [This](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040sd#idm140312990149616) would probably be a better source for the claim that wash sales do not apply to cryptocurrencies (based on it not being a stock or security).

Comment: @chepner The definition of "security" includes an "investment contract". Whether or not particular cryptocurrencies are or aren't investment contracts is a widely debated issue.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't know the details, but that kind of argument is precisely why I don't consider a blanket statement from somebody outside the IRS an authoritative source.

Comment: @chepner I'd love to see something from the IRS on this that explicitly mentions cryptocurrency.

Comment: I think even a qualified statement like "wash sale does not apply if the cryptocurrency is not a stock or security", backed by the applicable IRS citation, would be better than what amounts to an unsubstantiated claim by a 3rd party. Ultimately, why do we believe Levine is correct (assuming he is)?

Answer (score 6):

### Since all the *sales* are in the same tax year, you're fine

Crypto-"currencies" don't tax like recognized currencies, just regular securities like stocks.

Capital gains are taxable **when you sell** the stock/security.

Likewise, capital losses are only created *when you sell*.

So if you sell this year, your gains and your losses happen inside the same tax year.

### Capital gains and losses cancel-out and reconcile within the same tax year.

They will cancel each other out right on the Schedule D (*actually* right on the Form 8949, which is a tally sheet for Schedule D). Based on your starting point of $10,000 and endpoint of $12,000, expect to pay taxes on $2000.

Maybe you should grab a real Schedule D and 8949 and *fill it out* for the trades you have done so far.  Do a dry-run through the forms, and see how the numbers come out.

### Capital losses carry forward - capital gains do not.

What would suck is if you had the $40,000 of capital gains in 2020, and then had $38,000 in capital losses in 2021.   In that case, yeah, there's no way to carryforward capital *gains* to later tax years to cancel out losses then.

You are, however, allowed to carry-forward capital *losses* from year to year (and also deduct $3000/year of net losses).  Hypothetically if you lost $38,000 in 2020 and gained $40,000 in 2021, you could deduct $3000 in 2020, carry $35,000 loss forward to 2021 and use it to cancel out $35,000 of the capital gains, paying tax on only $5000.  (effectively paying the tax on the $3000 you avoided paying taxes on the year before).

Comment: The gains and losses are happening in the same year if and only if the OP sells at a loss before the end of the year.

Comment: @ben good point, emphasized.